# Syntax error, where to add "}" to complete classbody?

Tags: java, syntax-error

I have this code in eclipse but it looks like, it has a Syntax error (Line 168) - I should insert "}" to complete ClassBody. Please could you help me with it? Because I suck at inserting code here, you can look at it also here http://www.camrumble.com/source/opensource_chatroulette_9.jsp

```
 package com.rtmpclient;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.red5.server.api.IConnection;
import org.red5.server.api.IScope;
import org.red5.server.api.service.IServiceCapableConnection;

public class UserContainer extends ArrayList<user>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // --------------------------------- ACTION METHOD

    public void addUser(IConnection conn, IScope scope, String id, boolean cameraRequired){
        this.add(new User(conn, scope, id, cameraRequired));
    }

    public void disconnectUser(String id){
        for(User user : this){
            if(id.equals(user.getId())){
                removePartner(user.getId());
                this.remove(user);  
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void findPartner(String id) {
        User user = findUser(id);
        if (user != null) {
            if(!user.isAlive()){
                return;
            }
            user.setConnected(true);
            user.setAcceptConnection(true);
            if (user.getPartnerId() == null) {
                int startLoop = (int) (Math.random() * this.size());
                boolean upside = (Math.random() >= 0.5);
                User randomUser;
                outer: if (upside) {
                    // forward
                    for (int i = startLoop; i < this.size(); i++) {
                        randomUser = this.get(i);
                        if(!randomUser.isAlive()){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!randomUser.getId().equals(id) && randomUser.getPartnerId() == null && randomUser.isConnected() && randomUser.isAcceptConnection()) {
                            // check for camera status
                            if ((user.isCameraRequired() && !randomUser.isCameraConnected()) || (randomUser.isCameraRequired() && !user.isCameraConnected())) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            user.setPartnerId(randomUser.getId());
                            randomUser.setPartnerId(id);

                            // attach peer
                            randomUser.peerConnect(id, user.getStatusMessage(), user.isCameraConnected());
                            user.peerConnect(randomUser.getId(), randomUser.getStatusMessage(), randomUser.isCameraConnected());

                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                    // rewind
                    for (int i = startLoop; i >= 0; i--) {
                        randomUser = this.get(i);
                        if(!randomUser.isAlive()){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!randomUser.getId().equals(id) && randomUser.getPartnerId() == null && randomUser.isConnected() && randomUser.isAcceptConnection()) {
                            // check for camera status
                            if ((user.isCameraRequired() && !randomUser.isCameraConnected()) || (randomUser.isCameraRequired() && !user.isCameraConnected())) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            user.setPartnerId(randomUser.getId());
                            randomUser.setPartnerId(id);

                            // attach peer
                            randomUser.peerConnect(id, user.getStatusMessage(), user.isCameraConnected());
                            user.peerConnect(randomUser.getId(), randomUser.getStatusMessage(), randomUser.isCameraConnected());

                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    // forward
                    for (int i = startLoop; i >= 0; i--) {
                        randomUser = this.get(i);
                        if(!randomUser.isAlive()){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!randomUser.getId().equals(id) && randomUser.getPartnerId() == null && randomUser.isConnected() && randomUser.isAcceptConnection()) {
                            // check for camera status
                            if ((user.isCameraRequired() && !randomUser.isCameraConnected()) || (randomUser.isCameraRequired() && !user.isCameraConnected())) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            user.setPartnerId(randomUser.getId());
                            randomUser.setPartnerId(id);

                            // attach peer
                            randomUser.peerConnect(id, user.getStatusMessage(), user.isCameraConnected());
                            user.peerConnect(randomUser.getId(), randomUser.getStatusMessage(), randomUser.isCameraConnected());

                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                    // rewind
                    for (int i = startLoop; i < this.size(); i++) {
                        randomUser = this.get(i);
                        if(!randomUser.isAlive()){
                            continue;
                        }
                        if (!randomUser.getId().equals(id) && randomUser.getPartnerId() == null && randomUser.isConnected() && randomUser.isAcceptConnection()) {

                            // check for camera status
                            if ((user.isCameraRequired() && !randomUser.isCameraConnected()) || (randomUser.isCameraRequired() && !user.isCameraConnected())) {
                                continue;
                            }

                            user.setPartnerId(randomUser.getId());
                            randomUser.setPartnerId(id);

                            // attach peer
                            randomUser.peerConnect(id, user.getStatusMessage(), user.isCameraConnected());
                            user.peerConnect(randomUser.getId(), randomUser.getStatusMessage(), randomUser.isCameraConnected());

                            break outer;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (user.getPartnerId() == null) {
                // notify for no available connections
                IServiceCapableConnection service = (IServiceCapableConnection) user.getConn();
                service.invoke("noAvailableConnections");
            }
        }
    }

    public User findUser(String id){
        if(id != null){
            for(User user : this){
                if(id.equals(user.getId())){
                    return user;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void removePartner(String fromId){
        User user = findUser(fromId);
        if(user != null){
            User partner = findUser(user.getPartnerId());
            if(partner != null && partner.getPartnerId().equals(fromId)){
                //clear yourself from partner
                partner.setPartnerId(null);

                //notify partner
                IServiceCapableConnection service = (IServiceCapableConnection)partner.getConn();
                service.invoke("partnerIsDisconnected");
            }
            //clear partner from user
            user.setPartnerId(null);
        }
    }
}



    </user>
```

Comment: What's "
    </user>" doing at the end?  Get an IDE to help you with this (simple) problem.

Comment: On a side note, in OOP, as a rule of thumb, prefer composition over inheritance.

Comment: @Behrang Saeedzadeh perhaps *in Java "OOP"* ... put down the brainwashing cap ^^

Comment: @pst: favouring composition over inheritance IS a good principle.

Comment: @pst: this is theoretical OO and is not specific to Java. In fact some languages provide constructs that make composition and delegation easier.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're confusing generics with HTML/XML tags. In `ArrayList<user>`, `<user>` is not a start tag. It's a type parameter. Read this [trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) in Java Tutorial to understand what generics are and how you should use them.

Also, it looks like it should be `User`, not `user`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are missing a } the compiler will already have told you where, but surely it is just at the end of the file?

Comment: Well I tried to delete the `</user>` at the end and it looks like that it has no errors now. I hope it was not needed...

Comment: @user984902: You might consider opening a book. You can't guess at this stuff.

Comment: @user98492 </user>? Needed? It's not only not 'needed', it is positively illegal *anywhere* inside a Java program other than in a string literal. This is the Java Programming Language, not just a guessing game.

Answer (score 0):

first off you're better off using composition instead of inheritance (you can inherit [AbstractList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) and provide implementation for `get(int)` and `size()` by forwarding to a private ArrayList)

second divide up `findPartner` into smaller methods (I'm looking that that major `outer: if (upside) {...}else{...}` construct extract it to ) this will make everything more readable

you can at least start with saving an indentation level using

```
User user = findUser(id);
if (user == null || !user.isAlive() || user.getPartnerID() != null) {
    return;
}
```

third my eclipse shows me that all brackets are properly nested